# Passing data between WPF forms

Tags: c#, wpf, button

`form1` has a `button btnInvoke` which invokes `form2`. `form2` contains a `textbox` and a `button btn2`.

The user has to enter data in `textbox` and press `btn2`.

When `btn2` is clicked `form2` has to send `textbox data` to `form1`.

I have tried passing through constructors but I cant initiate a new instance of `form1`.

What shall I do?

Comment: Show your code of what you have tried.

Comment: Create an event in form2, and get form1 to subscribe to it. Then when btn2 is clicked, call the event.

Comment: Look at Application.Current.Properties

Answer (score 10):

There are two methods that you can use. The first of which would be using ShowDialog and a public method then testing that the DialogResult is true then reading the value from the method.

i.e.

```
if (newWindow.ShowDialog() == true)
            this.Title = newWindow.myText();
```

The second method would be to create a CustomEvent and subscribe to it in the creating window like this.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 newWindow = new Window1();
        newWindow.RaiseCustomEvent += new EventHandler<CustomEventArgs>(newWindow_RaiseCustomEvent);
        newWindow.Show();

    }

    void newWindow_RaiseCustomEvent(object sender, CustomEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Title = e.Message;
    }
}
```

**Window1.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> RaiseCustomEvent;

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string myText()
    {
        return textBox1.Text;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        RaiseCustomEvent(this, new CustomEventArgs(textBox1.Text));
    }
}
public class CustomEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public CustomEventArgs(string s)
    {
        msg = s;
    }
    private string msg;
    public string Message
    {
        get { return msg; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `form1` define a public property.

```
public string MyTextData { get; set; }
```

In your `form2` on button click, get the instance of the `form1`  and set it property to the TextBox value.

```
var frm1 = Application.Current.Windows["form1"] as Form1;
if(frm1 ! = null)
    frm1.MyTextData  = yourTextBox.Text;
```

In your `Form1` you will get the text in your property `MyTextData`

Its better if you following the convention for naming the windows. Use `Window` instead of `Form` for naming your windows in WPF.  Form is usually used with WinForm applications.

Comment: "form1" doesn't work. It has to be an int. What int?

Answer (score 1):

It may be overkill but an `EventAggregator` may be a nice solution here. It would allow you to raise an event in `form1` that could then be subscribed to from `form2`.

There are some details and examples of implementing an `EventAggregator` in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343980/event-aggregator-implementation-sample-best-practices.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with the WPF, use [CommandBindings](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238657/How-to-use-Commands-in-WPF) and [Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502686/mvvm-messaging-or-events-or-what-other-option-out-therer). I also recommend you that you take a closser look at MVVM Frameworks, I prevere the [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/). There are a lot of HowTos for the framework, just ask google.