# WPF/SQL - how to get tables from a selected database into a ListView

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

Good evening,

i'm at the beginning of an IT apprenticeship and i've started my own little project. I've got following problem:

I've created in WPF a standard Login Window for getting SQL Connection Datas. This Window is working fine and i only can switch to the next window when the entered Login-Datas are correct. My problem is the second window. In the second one i have one ListBox for listing every Database from the connected Server. Next to this ListBox i've a ListView. In this ListView i want to see the tables from the selected Database.

Code for listing Databases:

```
SqlConnection GetConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=admin-pc;user Id=sa;Password=123;");
try
{
   this.libDatabase.Items.Clear();
   DataTable databases = new DataTable("Databases");

   using (IDbConnection connection = GetConnection)
   {
      IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
      command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM sys.Databases";
      connection.Open();
      databases.Load(command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection));
   }
   this.libDatabase.Items.Clear();

   foreach (DataRow row in databases.Rows)
        this.libDatabase.Items.Add(row[0].ToString());
   }
   catch (SqlException)
   {
      this.libDatabase.Items.Clear();
      this.libDatabase.Items.Add("Connection error");
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Error while loading available databases");
   }
   finally
   {
      GetConnection.Close();
   }
```

libDatabase is the name of the ListBox.

This Code is working good and every Database is shown in my ListBox. But no i've a totally Blackout. How do i get the Tables from the selected Database into the ListView? I've tried the same way like i did with the Databases but with a different "SELECT"-Statement ==> **"select * from {0}", listbox.SelectedItem**
Here are different Codes i've tried but i think that i do something completely wrong.

First Version:

```
            List<ListViewItem> gettables = new List<ListViewItem>();
        if (libDatabase.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=admin-pc;user Id=sa;Password=123;");
            string strSQL = string.Format("select * from {0}", libDatabase.SelectedItem);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con);

            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {

            }


            reader.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
```

Second Version:

```
SqlConnection GetConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=admin-pc;user Id=sa;Password=123;");
        try
        {
            this.libTables.Items.Clear();
            DataTable tables = new DataTable("Tables");
            using (IDbConnection connection = GetConnection)
            {
                IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                if (libDatabase.SelectedItem != null)
                {
                    command.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", libDatabase.SelectedItem);
                    connection.Open();
                    tables.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
                }
            }
            this.libTables.Items.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow row in tables.Rows)
                this.libTables.Items.Add(row[0].ToString());
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            this.libTables.Items.Clear();
            this.libTables.Items.Add("Connection error. Check server");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error while loading available tables" + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            GetConnection.Close();
        }
```

libTables is the name of the ListView.

Maybe i did it completely wrong or there's just one code block false.

Thank you for supporting.

Dave S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this select statement instead:

```
               command.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}.sys.tables", libDatabase.SelectedItem);
```

As the database names are to be found in `sys.databases` within `master`, so too the tables are to be found within `sys.tables` for each database.

It pays to step through code of this nature with a debugger, and/or put a breakpoint at each meaningful location.  Verify each sql statement built in the code is *exactly* what you intended, and execute each statement within Sql Management studio using the same permissions under which it is being executed within your code, to ensure the statement will produce the results you want.

**Edit for triggering the table load:**

You must also ensure the table-loading process is triggered by the appropriate action.  In this case, it would most likely need to be triggered by the user selecting a database within the database listbox.  You'll need to add an event handler for the SelectionChanged event to the listbox.  (Note that I'm assuming you're not using the MVVM pattern based on the code samples you included in your question.)

Add the SelectionChanged attribute to your ListBox definition:

```
<ListBox Name="libDatabase" SelectionChanged="libDatabase_SelectionChanged">
```

And in the codebehind, define the event handler:

```
private void libDatabase_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(libDatabase.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        // open a database connection and select your tables here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this isn't working either!

I think there's a problem with libDatabase.SelectedItem?? Or should i put this code block in the same method as the database code block is?? It's the window_loaded code block. But i don't want to see the tables when the window is loaded. Only when a database is selected.

Comment: It's not clear where you have the second chunk of code (the table loading process).  From what you have stated, it sounds like you would want the tables loading in response to the database listbox's SelectionChanged event.  Is this where the table-loading code is?

Comment: in `private void Window_Loaded` i have the database list loaded because when the window opens the databases should be in the listbox. In `private void livTables_SelectionChanged` i want to load the table list from the selected database.

Comment: I've modified my answer to include a section on the libDatabase_SelectionChanged event you'll need.  You should load the tables in reaction to a database selection change occurring, not a table selection occurring.  It sounds like you've got it hooked up to the SelectionChanged event for the wrong control.

Comment: Oh ok now i know! I have the `SelectionChanged="lbTodoList_SelectionChanged` not in the ListBox tag but in the ListView tag. Maybe that's my problem.

Comment: Good to hear!  If the answer was helpful, feel free to mark it as accepted and upvote it... Thanks :)

Comment: OK THANK YOU SO MUCH. This problem is solved. I've just one more question: How do i get the entered login datas from the login window into this window?? In the login window i just use `txtbServer.Text` but i can't use that in the second window. Because i want that the shown databases are from the logged in server. (sorry my IT english is really bad).

Comment: There are a number of ways depending on how you are instantiating the windows; most likely you can just grab the fields you need from the first after it is done displaying and set some attributes in the second before it is shown.  Check out the thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433935/passing-data-between-wpf-forms) for some more ideas.  Good luck!

Comment: thank you so much! i was a little bit afraid to ask a question in stackoverflow as a beginner. (and with german as mothertongue)