# Access variable value from one window in another one

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm relatively new to C# and I have an question regarding how to access a variable from one window in another one. I want to do something like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
int foo=5;
....
}
```

and in window2:

```
public partial class Window2: Window
{
int bar=foo;
}
```

How should I do that? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class WindowBase : Window
{
    protected static int foo = 5;

    public int Foo
    {
        get
        {
            return foo;
        }
        set
        {
            foo = value;
        }
    }
}

public partial class Window1 : WindowBase
{
    public Window1()
    {
        int bar = base.Foo;

    }
}

public partial class Window2 : WindowBase
{
    public Window2()
    {
        int bar = base.Foo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In a program with fixed variables, the above answers will do good. But if you want to access a variable that is dynamically changed while running, it's better to make a separate class (separate file) to work as an *interface between the two window classes*.

For the sake of this example, let's assume this 'separate' class is stored inside `funkyFolder`. We have to initialize the variable inside this class.

/funkyFolder/DataInterface.cs:

```
namespace fooDemo.funkyFolder
{
    public static class DataInterface
    {
        public static int fooVal = 0;
    }
}
```

Now, in the first window, you can change the variable data dynamically. *Ps: remember to add* `using fooDemo.funkyFolder`

```
using fooDemo.funkyFolder;
namespace fooDemo
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private void btnHello_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataInterface.fooVal = 10;
        }

    }
}
```

Then, in the second window, you can access the variable without any problem.

```
using fooDemo.funkyFolder;
namespace fooDemo
{
    public partial class SecondWindow : Window
    {
        public CartPage()
        {
             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(DataInterface.fooVal);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put these variables into a static class:

```
static class MyVariables
{
    public static int foo;
}
```

In MainWindow, you can set the value of this variable:

```
MyVariables.foo = 5;
```

And in Window2, you can request the value:

```
int bar = MyVariables.foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you'll have to make your variable `public`:

```
public int foo = 5;
```

For accessing, create instance of `MainWindow`:

```
MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
bar = mw.foo;
```

Comment: This snippet technically works if the foo value is fixed, and does not require to be changed on the run. But, if foo is a computed value inside the `first class` (window) and you need to access that value in the `second class`, you **cant** take in that value. --Because you know, you are creating a new object with `MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in **multiple** ways. It depends upon your usage though.

You can expose properties from your Window2 (assuming this form is invoked by MainWindow).

```
public partial class Window2: Window
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Then in MainWindow you can set this property.

**Or** You can create a **singelton** as data share. *Though, I will not recommend that.*

**or** You can also refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433935/passing-data-between-wpf-forms) but assuming you are just starting C# I think it might be slightly complicated.