# Using a combobox to populate a datagrid in another window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, datagrid

I have a combo box in one window and a data grid in another, I want to be able to select an item from the combo box and click a button to take me to the next window where it contains a data grid with all the information based on the selected item in the combo box. I was just wondering if this is possible to pass data between windows.

Comment: Save the data in one place, and populate the combox box from that data, and also the grid based on what that data contains about the selected item. Don't pass a bunch of data around (that is pejoratively called "tramp data").

Comment: @abr of course this is possible why is this so hard for you to do can you show exactly what you have tried thus far..?

Comment: I am using a database as the source for the combo box and datagrid so the query for the datagrid needs to be 'select * from name WHERE combobox is ??'. am i right in this logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're searching for a way to passe data from a form to another 
there are many ways to do so here is a link to a great response for such a question : [passing data between wpf forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433935/passing-data-between-wpf-forms)