# Is it possible to pass listBox selected Items from one wpf page to another

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I am trying to select multiple items on a listbox and when a button is pressed those items get moved to another listbox on a separate page. Perhaps i need to use serialization or a storage folder?

Comment: This may be useful: [Passing data between WPF forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433935/passing-data-between-wpf-forms)

Answer (score 0):

If both pages are opened by the same application, you can just have a property in one of the pages, which will reference the property in the other page and some event, that will fire on when the button will be pressed.